# Read words from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which contains words. Example: 
    string s = " asd qwert 123 ";
How can I read asd qwert and 123 from the string seperately with a loop in c#?
Thanx in advance

Comment: just split the string by space.

Comment: @Shaharyar The OP wants to split on space, not a multi-character delimiter.  I'm sure there's a dup for this, but that's not the right one.

Comment: `String[] words = s.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` then itterate by `words`

Answer (score 2):

If you make use of the `Split` method you can do so quite easily:

```
foreach(var str in s.Split(' '))
{
     // str would be one of asd, qwert and 123
     // since splitting on whitespace gives you an array 
     // with the words in the string s, which are separated one
     // from the other with a whitespace between them.  
}
```

Please have a look [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split).

Comment: The OP might need to use the overload that takes a `StringSplitOptions` and pass in  `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`